# $update not a function using $resource?

Tags: angularjs

I want update document using two ids using $resource.my api root is like this

```
$resource("http://192.168.0.2:3060/product/:subid/:productid",{"subid": "@subid"},{"productid": "@productid"},{update:{method:"PUT"}});
```

i got the error like this.
subproduct.$update is not a function

My Factory Like this:

```
ZustShopFactoryModule.factory("SubMenuItemFactory",function($resource,$q,RES_URL){
var subproductinfo=[]
var subproductresource=$resource("http://192.168.0.2:3060/product/:subid/:productid",{"subid": "@subid"},{"productid": "@productid"},{update:{method:"PUT"}});
return{
updatesubproductItem:function(SubMenuItem,idx){
        var subproduct=new subproductresource(SubMenuItem,SubMenuItem.subid);
        console.log(subproduct)
        console.log(SubMenuItem.subid)
        console.log(SubMenuItem._id)
        subproduct.$update({"subid":SubMenuItem.subid,"productid": SubMenuItem._id},function(data){
            console.log(data)
             subproductinfo[idx]=data;
            console.log("Updated...")
        },function(){
            console.log("Not Updated...")
        })
    }

}
   })
```

please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting **update** in quotes like so:

```
$resource("http://192.168.0.2:3060/product/:subid/:productid",
  {"subid": "@subid"},{"productid": "@productid"},
  {
    'update': {method:"PUT"}
  });
```

You also might be using **new** wrong. **new** usually takes one argument which is the resource to be created as a JSON object. If the above fix doesn't work, what is the output of your console.logs?